# Why i see DST="127.0.0.53" on -j REDIRECTed packets?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, iptables, dnsmasq

I am confused about situation in my NATed network. I start `dnsmasq` on router, with `listen-address=192.168.100.1` and `-p 5353` option for DNS port. Afterwards, i add iptables rule for hosts inside that network:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 \
    -d 192.168.100.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5353
```

But this didn't work first time, since my `INPUT` policy is `DROP`: when i add this rule, everything starts to work:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 127.0.0.53 -j ACCEPT
```

I discovered this address with help of `-j LOG` on my `INPUT` chain, where i saw packets dropped like `SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.53 ...`, when NATed host is trying to resolve hostname.

As i am writing automated script that generates correct netfilter rules for situation, i need to know from where this **127.0.0.53** could come from.

I see the same address in `/etc/resolv.conf`. But i don't understand who's routing this packet to this address when it is "redirected", if even close to understanding what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-resolved sets up a stub listener for dns requests locally on 127.0.0.53:53

try disabling it to proceed `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved`